# Simple issue working with streams

Tags: .net, vb.net, stream, rtf, css

I'm trying to use a third party library (a demo, so I can't get support) that provides Classes to transform HTML to RTf and others, the problem is that the method that I'm using expects a `System.Io.Stream` to store the RTF transformation but I'm not able to set it correctlly, my stream stills empty.

I think that I'm missing something about the usage of my Stream because I never needed to use a Stream so I really don't know if I'm using the Stream object correctlly.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
Imports Nasosoft.Documents.Transform
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown

        ' Set the Stream.
        Dim RTFStream As Stream = Stream.Null

        ' Create a HtmlToRtfTransform
        Dim Converter As HtmlToRtfTransform = New HtmlToRtfTransform()

        ' Load an HTML file.
        Converter.Load("C:\File.html", System.Text.Encoding.Default)

        ' Transform it into a stream
        Converter.Transform(RTFStream)

        ' Transform it into a file
        ' Converter.Transform("C:\File.rtf") ' This works well.

        ' Dispose the object.
        ' Converter.Dispose()

        MsgBox(RTFStream.Length) ' Result: '0' ...

        ' I try to read the contents of the Stream
        Dim StrReader As New StreamReader(RTFStream)
        MsgBox(StrReader.ReadToEnd) ' But there is nothing to see.

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: the stream is null, and is never set to the file - maybe

Comment: @DonA no, it isn't *null*; it is `/dev/nul`; i.e. an eternal chasm of swallowingness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pushing everything into the null stream (`Stream.Null`); what that does is *throw everything away*. That is *all* it does.

Try using a new `MemoryStream` instead, also making sure to rewind it after putting data in, and before reading it (set the `Position` to `0`).

From MSDN on `Stream.Null`:

> Use `Null` to redirect output to a stream that will not consume any operating system resources. When the methods of `Stream` that provide writing are invoked on `Null`, the call simply returns, and no data is written. `Null` also implements a `Read` method that returns zero without reading data.

Answer (score 0):

Just I want to share an Helper Class that I've write thanks to @Marc Gravell solution.

```
#Region " Imports "

Imports Nasosoft.Documents.Transform
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

#End Region

''' <summary>
''' Performs document conversion operations.
''' </summary>
Public Class DocumentConverter

#Region " Public Methods "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Converts RTF text to HTML.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="RtfText">Indicates the RTF text.</param>
    ''' <returns>System.String.</returns>
    Public Shared Function Rtf2Html(ByVal RtfText As String,
                                    Optional ByVal TextEncoding As Encoding = Nothing) As String

        TextEncoding = If(TextEncoding Is Nothing, Encoding.Default, TextEncoding)

        Dim RtfStream As New MemoryStream(TextEncoding.GetBytes(RtfText))
        Dim HtmlStream As New MemoryStream
        Dim HtmlText As String = String.Empty

        Using Converter As New RtfToHtmlTransform()
            Converter.Load(RtfStream)
            Converter.Transform(HtmlStream)
        End Using

        HtmlStream.Position = 0

        Using StrReader As New StreamReader(HtmlStream)
            HtmlText = StrReader.ReadToEnd
        End Using

        RtfStream.Close()
        HtmlStream.Close()

        Return HtmlText

    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Converts RTF text to TXT (Plain text).
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="RtfText">Indicates the RTF text.</param>
    ''' <returns>System.String.</returns>
    Public Shared Function Rtf2Txt(ByVal RtfText As String,
                                    Optional ByVal TextEncoding As Encoding = Nothing) As String

        TextEncoding = If(TextEncoding Is Nothing, Encoding.Default, TextEncoding)

        Dim RtfStream As New MemoryStream(TextEncoding.GetBytes(RtfText))
        Dim TextStream As New MemoryStream
        Dim PlainText As String = String.Empty

        Using Converter As New RtfToTextTransform()
            Converter.Load(RtfStream)
            Converter.Transform(TextStream)
        End Using

        TextStream.Position = 0

        Using StrReader As New StreamReader(TextStream)
            PlainText = StrReader.ReadToEnd
        End Using

        RtfStream.Close()
        TextStream.Close()

        Return PlainText

    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Converts HTML text to RTF.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="HtmlText">Indicates the HTML text.</param>
    ''' <returns>System.String.</returns>
    Public Shared Function Html2Rtf(ByVal HtmlText As String,
                                    Optional ByVal TextEncoding As Encoding = Nothing) As String

        TextEncoding = If(TextEncoding Is Nothing, Encoding.Default, TextEncoding)

        Dim HtmlStream As New MemoryStream(TextEncoding.GetBytes(HtmlText))
        Dim RtfStream As New MemoryStream
        Dim RtfText As String = String.Empty

        Using Converter As New HtmlToRtfTransform()
            Converter.Load(HtmlStream)
            Converter.Transform(RtfStream)
        End Using

        RtfStream.Position = 0

        Using StrReader As New StreamReader(RtfStream)
            RtfText = StrReader.ReadToEnd
        End Using

        HtmlStream.Close()
        RtfStream.Close()

        Return RtfText

    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Converts HTML text to TXT (Plain text).
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="HtmlText">Indicates the HTML text.</param>
    ''' <returns>System.String.</returns>
    Public Shared Function HtmlTxt(ByVal HtmlText As String,
                                   Optional ByVal TextEncoding As Encoding = Nothing) As String

        TextEncoding = If(TextEncoding Is Nothing, Encoding.Default, TextEncoding)

        Dim HtmlStream As New MemoryStream(TextEncoding.GetBytes(HtmlText))
        Dim TextStream As New MemoryStream
        Dim PlainText As String = String.Empty

        Using Converter As New HtmlToTextTransform()
            Converter.Load(HtmlStream)
            Converter.Transform(TextStream)
        End Using

        TextStream.Position = 0

        Using StrReader As New StreamReader(TextStream)
            PlainText = StrReader.ReadToEnd
        End Using

        HtmlStream.Close()
        TextStream.Close()

        Return PlainText

    End Function

#End Region

End Class
```